# Should I install Windows SDK after

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, winapi

I have Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I want to build Win32 applications and also its x64 build. No Windows Phone, neither windows store application is my concern.

Should I install Windows SDK in this case? If I want to install Windows SDK, is there any particular installation order I have to follow? (I heard that for VS2010 SPI and Windows SDK v7, there is a particular installation order.) Also, if I want to install Windows SDK, should I take Windows SDK v7.1 or SDK 8.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Tools, documentation, sample and OS support come and go. Only you can list what tool, documentation, sample or OS support you need, we cannot guess your mind. Multiple version of SDK can coexist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2012, you do not need to install anything additional to do this.
Make sure you've installed the 64-bit compiler binaries when installing Visual Studio.

By default, a project will be built for `Win32`.
To build for `x64`, select `Build -> Configuration Manager...`
Then from the `Active solution platform` drop down select `<New...>`
From the new platform drop down select `x64`.

After this you can build for `Win32` or `x64` by choosing the appropriate configuration from the configuration manager or you can build both by selecting `Build -> Batch Build...`